# Global Scope not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently trying to add the data from each JSON file in a specific folder to a string and then log that string to the console - but it's not working. Is anyone able to shed some light on where I'm going wrong?

```
global.article = "";
for(i=0;i<posts.length;i++){
  fs.readFile('posts/' + posts[i], 'utf8', function(err, json){
    var post = JSON.parse(json);
    article += "<article>";
    article += "<blockquote>";
    article += "<h3>" + post.title + "</h3>";
    article += "<small>" + post.date + "</small>";
    article += post.content;
    article += "</blockquote>";
    article += "</article>";
  });
}
console.log(article);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 'global.article', you should instead declare a new variable for the article.

```
var article = "";
```

If you need to update global.article when you have finished constructing the string in the loop, you can assign back to it when the loop exits.

```
global.article = article;
```

If for some reason you want to update global.article directly, you can update global.article instead, as shown in this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lkpe4/

HTH

Answer (score 1):

`fs.readFile` is asynchronous, so the `console.log(article);` at the bottom is going to run before any of your `fs.readFile` callbacks with the JSON processing that populates `article`.

Take a look at using the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library to provide asynchronous flow control, but a simple solution that illustrates that nature of the problem is to keep track of the callback count and only process `article` once they've all completed:

```
global.article = "";
var count = 0;
for(i=0;i<posts.length;i++){
    fs.readFile('posts/' + posts[i], 'utf8', function(err, json){
        var post = JSON.parse(json);
        article += "<article>";
        article += "<blockquote>";
        article += "<h3>" + post.title + "</h3>";
        article += "<small>" + post.date + "</small>";
        article += post.content;
        article += "</blockquote>";
        article += "</article>";
        if (++count === posts.length) {
            // All callbacks are now complete.
            console.log(article);
        }
   });
}
```